# How to change stepper icons foreground color in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'd like to change my steppers foreground color, and I can't find the property that works on it. I'd prefer to keep the standard stepper with the colors changed, and not have to create a custom one.

*accentColor* and *foregroundColor* don't work.

```swift
Stepper(value: $timer, in: 1...30) {
    Text("\(timer) " + "minutes")
        .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
    .accentColor(.red)
    .foregroundColor(.red)
}
```

This:

[image: before]

to this:

[image]

Is this even possible atm?

Comment: you can create own stepper rezlisation and do it with ANY design. Base swiftUI stepper does not support UI change

Comment: @Andrew Really, no customization on it at all, that's unfortunate.

Comment: There is customisation. But only on text related to stepper. Not on the buttons + and - as you expect: https://prnt.sc/18hxj8q

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set setDecrementImage, setIncrementImage images in view init..

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UIStepper.appearance().setDecrementImage(UIImage(systemName: "minus"), for: .normal)
        UIStepper.appearance().setIncrementImage(UIImage(systemName: "plus"), for: .normal)
    }
    var body: some View {
        Stepper(value: $timer, in: 1...30) {
            Text("\(timer) " + "minutes")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
            .accentColor(.red)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}
```